# Angular Google Chart - ERROR Error: Invalid row #0 When try to bind data with MongoDB data array

Tags: javascript, angular, mongodb, charts, google-visualization

I'm building a sankey chart that will get it's data from MongoDB array but when i open it return error.

```
ERROR Error: Invalid row #0
at Object.gvjs_ll [as arrayToDataTable]
at GoogleChartComponent.createDataTable
at SafeSubscriber._next
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub
at SafeSubscriber.next 
at Subscriber._next 
at Subscriber.next 
at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext
at InnerSubscriber._next 
at InnerSubscriber.next
```

This is the first time i use Google Chart, so i'm not sure why i'm having this error.
I try to look around a bit but didn't find any fix so i come here to ask.

I use the code for chart from [**Here**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular_googlecharts/angular_googlecharts_sankey_customized.htm)

**firstchart.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {BackendService} from './../backend.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'firstchart',
  templateUrl: './firstchart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./firstchart.component.css']
})
export class FirstchartComponent implements OnInit {

  public data: object[];

  title = '';
  type = 'Sankey';

  columnNames = ['From', 'To', 'Weight'];
  options = {       
  };
  width = 1820;
  height = 740;

  constructor(private myservice: BackendService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myservice.GetList().subscribe(
      (res: any) => { 
        this.data = res["0"]["list"];
      },
      error => { 
      }
    );
  }

}
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
const SLDBModel = require('./sldb_schema');         
require('./db');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use(function (req, res, next)
{
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','content-type, x-access-token');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});

app.get('/api/getList', function (req, res)
{   
    SLDBModel.find({},function(err, data)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            res.send(err);
        }
        else
        {   
            res.send(data.map(v => v.toJSON()));
        }
    });
});

module.exports = app;

app.listen(3000, ()=>
{
    console.log("SERVER IS ONLINE! ON PORT 3000");
})
```

**data in MongoDB**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec4672e44f01dcae82c3dde"),
    "num_rows" : 3,
    "list" : [ 
        {
            "From" : "All Population",
            "To" : "SBOBETH",
            "Weight" : 1,
            "S_NAME" : "SBOBETH",
            "S_ADD" : "sbobeth.com",
            "S_STATUS" : "UP",
            "S_DPV" : 565
        }, 
        {
            "From" : "All Population",
            "To" : "GTRCASINO",
            "Weight" : 1,
            "S_NAME" : "GTRCASINO",
            "S_ADD" : "gtrcasino.com",
            "S_STATUS" : "DOWN",
            "S_DPV" : 1680
        }, 
        {
            "From" : "All Population",
            "To" : "GTRBETCLUB",
            "Weight" : 1,
            "S_NAME" : "GTRBETCLUB",
            "S_ADD" : "gtrbetclub.com",
            "S_STATUS" : "UP",
            "S_DPV" : 4950
        }, 
        {
            "From" : "All Population",
            "To" : "77UP",
            "Weight" : 1,
            "S_NAME" : "77UP",
            "S_ADD" : "77up.bet",
            "S_STATUS" : "UP",
            "S_DPV" : 273
        }
    ]
}
```

**HTML**

```
<br>
<div style="text-align: center;">
   <google-chart #chart
      [title]="title"
      [type]="type"
      [data]="data"
      [columnNames]="columnNames"
      [options]="options"
      [width]="width"
      [height]="height">
   </google-chart>
</div>
<br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the data, you're passing an array of objects...

```
[ 
    {
        "From" : "All Population",
        "To" : "SBOBETH",
        "Weight" : 1,
        "S_NAME" : "SBOBETH",
        "S_ADD" : "sbobeth.com",
        "S_STATUS" : "UP",
        "S_DPV" : 565
    }, 
    {
        "From" : "All Population",
        "To" : "GTRCASINO",
        "Weight" : 1,
        "S_NAME" : "GTRCASINO",
        "S_ADD" : "gtrcasino.com",
        "S_STATUS" : "DOWN",
        "S_DPV" : 1680
    }, 
    ...
]
```

but the chart expects an array of arrays...

```
[ 
    ["All Population", "SBOBETH", 1],
    ["All Population", "GTRCASINO", 1],
    ...
]
```

try converting the data as follows...

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.myservice.GetList().subscribe(
    (res: any) => { 
      this.data = res[0].list.map(row => {
        return [row.From, row.To, row.Weight];
      });
    },
    error => { 
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: i got `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` how can i fix it?

Comment: that is saying `res.list` is undefined. did something change with the data?

Comment: No, i only change what you have suggested.

Comment: will you please share the result of the following? --> `console.log(JSON.stringify(res));`

Comment: [{"_id":"5ec4672e44f01dcae82c3dde","num_rows":3,"list":[{"From":"All Population","To":"SBOBETH","Weight":1,"S_NAME":"SBOBETH","S_ADD":"sbobeth.com","S_STATUS":"UP","S_DPV":565},{"From":"All Population","To":"GTRCASINO","Weight":1,"S_NAME":"GTRCASINO","S_ADD":"gtrcasino.com","S_STATUS":"DOWN","S_DPV":1680},{"From":"All Population","To":"GTRBETCLUB","Weight":1,"S_NAME":"GTRBETCLUB","S_ADD":"gtrbetclub.com","S_STATUS":"UP","S_DPV":4950},{"From":"All Population","To":"77UP","Weight":1,"S_NAME":"77UP","S_ADD":"77up.bet","S_STATUS":"UP","S_DPV":273}]}]

Comment: so this is different than what you posted in the question. changed my answer, see above. use --> `res[0].list.map`

Comment: Oh, that's work Thanks alot,  But how was that different tho? can you point it out for me?

Comment: the data you posted in the comment is wrapped in an array, which wasn't included in the question.